# C# build JSON string that has semicolons in the data

Tags: c#, json, escaping

I am creating a string as follows:

```
string title = "Q:hello";
```

I then want to embed this string in a JSON string to send to the client.  How do I escape the semicolon?  I don't want to use a library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the spec, only characters that need escaping are ", \, and control-character:

```
\"
\\
\/
\b
\f
\n
\r
\t
```

so you don't need to escape semicolon in a Json string. Ref: http://www.json.org/ (on the right side)

Answer (score 0):

Try using backslash  http://json.org/

Even though you don't  want libraries try look at the JavaScriptSerializer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx

its standard .net so you won't add dependencies. (Although it requires a reference to System.Web.Extensions)